# Type not found in NameSpace in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am new in Xamarin & I have an issue while working with Xamarin forms. I have added in new file in my namespace with name *NamedColor.cs* and in my *ListViewDemoPage.xaml* file I have added below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ListViewDemo;assembly=ListViewDemo" 
    x:Class="ListViewDemo.ListViewDemoPage"
>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Static local:NamedColor.All}" />
</ContentPage>
```

But at run time I am getting type not found exception (please see below error screen shot)

[image]

Can any one suggest me what am I doing wrong as a beginner?

Below is my *NamedColor.cs* file code

```
   using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace ListViewDemo
{
    public class NamedColor
    {
        // Instance members.
        private NamedColor()
        {
        }

        public string Name { private set; get; }

        public string FriendlyName { private set; get; }

        public Color Color { private set; get; }

        // Static members.
        static NamedColor()
        {
            List<NamedColor> all = new List<NamedColor>();
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            // Loop through the public static fields of type Color.
            foreach (FieldInfo fieldInfo in 
                            typeof (NamedColor).GetRuntimeFields ())
            {
                if (fieldInfo.IsPublic &&
                    fieldInfo.IsStatic &&
                    fieldInfo.FieldType == typeof (Color))
                {
                    // Convert the name to a friendly name.
                    string name = fieldInfo.Name;
                    stringBuilder.Clear();
                    int index = 0;

                    foreach (char ch in name)
                    {
                        if (index != 0 && Char.IsUpper(ch))
                        {
                            stringBuilder.Append(' ');
                        }
                        stringBuilder.Append(ch);
                        index++;
                    }

                    // Instantiate a NamedColor object.
                    NamedColor namedColor = new NamedColor
                    {
                        Name = name,
                        FriendlyName = stringBuilder.ToString(),
                        Color = (Color)fieldInfo.GetValue(null)
                    };

                    // Add it to the collection.
                    all.Add(namedColor);
                }
            }
            all.TrimExcess();
            All = all;
        }

        public static IEnumerable<NamedColor> All { private set; get; }

        // Color names and definitions from http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/
        // (but with color names converted to camel case).
        public static readonly Color AliceBlue = Color.FromRgb(240, 248, 255);
        public static readonly Color AntiqueWhite = Color.FromRgb(250, 235, 215);
        public static readonly Color Aqua = Color.FromRgb(0, 255, 255);
        public static readonly Color Aquamarine = Color.FromRgb(127, 255, 212);
        public static readonly Color Azure = Color.FromRgb(240, 255, 255);
        public static readonly Color Beige = Color.FromRgb(245, 245, 220);
        public static readonly Color Bisque = Color.FromRgb(255, 228, 196);
        public static readonly Color Black = Color.FromRgb(0, 0, 0);
        public static readonly Color BlanchedAlmond = Color.FromRgb(255, 235, 205);
        public static readonly Color Blue = Color.FromRgb(0, 0, 255);
        public static readonly Color BlueViolet = Color.FromRgb(138, 43, 226);
        public static readonly Color Brown = Color.FromRgb(165, 42, 42);
        public static readonly Color Burlywood = Color.FromRgb(222, 184, 135);
        public static readonly Color CadetBlue = Color.FromRgb(95, 158, 160);
        public static readonly Color Chartreuse = Color.FromRgb(127, 255, 0);
        public static readonly Color Chocolate = Color.FromRgb(210, 105, 30);
        public static readonly Color Coral = Color.FromRgb(255, 127, 80);
        public static readonly Color CornflowerBlue = Color.FromRgb(100, 149, 237);
        public static readonly Color Cornsilk = Color.FromRgb(255, 248, 220);
        public static readonly Color Crimson = Color.FromRgb(220, 20, 60);
        public static readonly Color Cyan = Color.FromRgb(0, 255, 255);
        public static readonly Color DarkBlue = Color.FromRgb(0, 0, 139);
        public static readonly Color DarkCyan = Color.FromRgb(0, 139, 139);
        public static readonly Color DarkGoldenrod = Color.FromRgb(184, 134, 11);
        public static readonly Color DarkGray = Color.FromRgb(169, 169, 169);
        public static readonly Color DarkGreen = Color.FromRgb(0, 100, 0);
        public static readonly Color DarkGrey = Color.FromRgb(169, 169, 169);
        public static readonly Color DarkKhaki = Color.FromRgb(189, 183, 107);
        public static readonly Color DarkMagenta = Color.FromRgb(139, 0, 139);
        public static readonly Color DarkOliveGreen = Color.FromRgb(85, 107, 47);
        public static readonly Color DarkOrange = Color.FromRgb(255, 140, 0);
        public static readonly Color DarkOrchid = Color.FromRgb(153, 50, 204);
        public static readonly Color DarkRed = Color.FromRgb(139, 0, 0);
        public static readonly Color DarkSalmon = Color.FromRgb(233, 150, 122);
        public static readonly Color DarkSeaGreen = Color.FromRgb(143, 188, 143);
        public static readonly Color DarkSlateBlue = Color.FromRgb(72, 61, 139);
        public static readonly Color DarkSlateGray = Color.FromRgb(47, 79, 79);
        public static readonly Color DarkSlateGrey = Color.FromRgb(47, 79, 79);
        public static readonly Color DarkTurquoise = Color.FromRgb(0, 206, 209);
        public static readonly Color DarkViolet = Color.FromRgb(148, 0, 211);
        public static readonly Color DeepPink = Color.FromRgb(255, 20, 147);
        public static readonly Color DeepSkyBlue = Color.FromRgb(0, 191, 255);
        public static readonly Color DimGray = Color.FromRgb(105, 105, 105);
        public static readonly Color DimGrey = Color.FromRgb(105, 105, 105);
        public static readonly Color DodgerBlue = Color.FromRgb(30, 144, 255);
        public static readonly Color Firebrick = Color.FromRgb(178, 34, 34);
        public static readonly Color FloralWhite = Color.FromRgb(255, 250, 240);
        public static readonly Color ForestGreen = Color.FromRgb(34, 139, 34);
        public static readonly Color Fuchsia = Color.FromRgb(255, 0, 255);
        public static readonly Color Gainsboro = Color.FromRgb(220, 220, 220);
        public static readonly Color GhostWhite = Color.FromRgb(248, 248, 255);
        public static readonly Color Gold = Color.FromRgb(255, 215, 0);
        public static readonly Color Goldenrod = Color.FromRgb(218, 165, 32);
        public static readonly Color Gray = Color.FromRgb(128, 128, 128);
        public static readonly Color Green = Color.FromRgb(0, 128, 0);
        public static readonly Color GreenYellow = Color.FromRgb(173, 255, 47);
        public static readonly Color Grey = Color.FromRgb(128, 128, 128);
        public static readonly Color Honeydew = Color.FromRgb(240, 255, 240);
        public static readonly Color HotPink = Color.FromRgb(255, 105, 180);
        public static readonly Color IndianRed = Color.FromRgb(205, 92, 92);
        public static readonly Color Indigo = Color.FromRgb(75, 0, 130);
        public static readonly Color Ivory = Color.FromRgb(255, 255, 240);
        public static readonly Color Khaki = Color.FromRgb(240, 230, 140);
        public static readonly Color Lavender = Color.FromRgb(230, 230, 250);
        public static readonly Color LavenderBlush = Color.FromRgb(255, 240, 245);
        public static readonly Color LawnGreen = Color.FromRgb(124, 252, 0);
        public static readonly Color LemonChiffon = Color.FromRgb(255, 250, 205);
        public static readonly Color LightBlue = Color.FromRgb(173, 216, 230);
        public static readonly Color LightCoral = Color.FromRgb(240, 128, 128);
        public static readonly Color LightCyan = Color.FromRgb(224, 255, 255);
        public static readonly Color LightGoldenrodYellow = Color.FromRgb(250, 250, 210);
        public static readonly Color LightGray = Color.FromRgb(211, 211, 211);
        public static readonly Color LightGreen = Color.FromRgb(144, 238, 144);
        public static readonly Color LightGrey = Color.FromRgb(211, 211, 211);
        public static readonly Color LightPink = Color.FromRgb(255, 182, 193);
        public static readonly Color LightSalmon = Color.FromRgb(255, 160, 122);
        public static readonly Color LightSeaGreen = Color.FromRgb(32, 178, 170);
        public static readonly Color LightSkyBlue = Color.FromRgb(135, 206, 250);
        public static readonly Color LightSlateGray = Color.FromRgb(119, 136, 153);
        public static readonly Color LightSlateGrey = Color.FromRgb(119, 136, 153);
        public static readonly Color LightSteelBlue = Color.FromRgb(176, 196, 222);
        public static readonly Color LightYellow = Color.FromRgb(255, 255, 224);
        public static readonly Color Lime = Color.FromRgb(0, 255, 0);
        public static readonly Color LimeGreen = Color.FromRgb(50, 205, 50);
        public static readonly Color Linen = Color.FromRgb(250, 240, 230);
        public static readonly Color Magenta = Color.FromRgb(255, 0, 255);
        public static readonly Color Maroon = Color.FromRgb(128, 0, 0);
        public static readonly Color MediumAquamarine = Color.FromRgb(102, 205, 170);
        public static readonly Color MediumBlue = Color.FromRgb(0, 0, 205);
        public static readonly Color MediumOrchid = Color.FromRgb(186, 85, 211);
        public static readonly Color MediumPurple = Color.FromRgb(147, 112, 219);
        public static readonly Color MediumSeaGreen = Color.FromRgb(60, 179, 113);
        public static readonly Color MediumSlateBlue = Color.FromRgb(123, 104, 238);
        public static readonly Color MediumSpringGreen = Color.FromRgb(0, 250, 154);
        public static readonly Color MediumTurquoise = Color.FromRgb(72, 209, 204);
        public static readonly Color MediumVioletRed = Color.FromRgb(199, 21, 133);
        public static readonly Color MidnightBlue = Color.FromRgb(25, 25, 112);
        public static readonly Color MintCream = Color.FromRgb(245, 255, 250);
        public static readonly Color MistyRose = Color.FromRgb(255, 228, 225);
        public static readonly Color Moccasin = Color.FromRgb(255, 228, 181);
        public static readonly Color NavajoWhite = Color.FromRgb(255, 222, 173);
        public static readonly Color Navy = Color.FromRgb(0, 0, 128);
        public static readonly Color OldLace = Color.FromRgb(253, 245, 230);
        public static readonly Color Olive = Color.FromRgb(128, 128, 0);
        public static readonly Color OliveDrab = Color.FromRgb(107, 142, 35);
        public static readonly Color Orange = Color.FromRgb(255, 165, 0);
        public static readonly Color OrangeRed = Color.FromRgb(255, 69, 0);
        public static readonly Color Orchid = Color.FromRgb(218, 112, 214);
        public static readonly Color PaleGoldenrod = Color.FromRgb(238, 232, 170);
        public static readonly Color PaleGreen = Color.FromRgb(152, 251, 152);
        public static readonly Color PaleTurquoise = Color.FromRgb(175, 238, 238);
        public static readonly Color PaleVioletRed = Color.FromRgb(219, 112, 147);
        public static readonly Color PapayaWhip = Color.FromRgb(255, 239, 213);
        public static readonly Color PeachPuff = Color.FromRgb(255, 218, 185);
        public static readonly Color Peru = Color.FromRgb(205, 133, 63);
        public static readonly Color Pink = Color.FromRgb(255, 192, 203);
        public static readonly Color Plum = Color.FromRgb(221, 160, 221);
        public static readonly Color PowderBlue = Color.FromRgb(176, 224, 230);
        public static readonly Color Purple = Color.FromRgb(128, 0, 128);
        public static readonly Color Red = Color.FromRgb(255, 0, 0);
        public static readonly Color RosyBrown = Color.FromRgb(188, 143, 143);
        public static readonly Color RoyalBlue = Color.FromRgb(65, 105, 225);
        public static readonly Color SaddleBrown = Color.FromRgb(139, 69, 19);
        public static readonly Color Salmon = Color.FromRgb(250, 128, 114);
        public static readonly Color SandyBrown = Color.FromRgb(244, 164, 96);
        public static readonly Color SeaGreen = Color.FromRgb(46, 139, 87);
        public static readonly Color SeaShell = Color.FromRgb(255, 245, 238);
        public static readonly Color Sienna = Color.FromRgb(160, 82, 45);
        public static readonly Color Silver = Color.FromRgb(192, 192, 192);
        public static readonly Color SkyBlue = Color.FromRgb(135, 206, 235);
        public static readonly Color SlateBlue = Color.FromRgb(106, 90, 205);
        public static readonly Color SlateGray = Color.FromRgb(112, 128, 144);
        public static readonly Color SlateGrey = Color.FromRgb(112, 128, 144);
        public static readonly Color Snow = Color.FromRgb(255, 250, 250);
        public static readonly Color SpringGreen = Color.FromRgb(0, 255, 127);
        public static readonly Color SteelBlue = Color.FromRgb(70, 130, 180);
        public static readonly Color Tan = Color.FromRgb(210, 180, 140);
        public static readonly Color Teal = Color.FromRgb(0, 128, 128);
        public static readonly Color Thistle = Color.FromRgb(216, 191, 216);
        public static readonly Color Tomato = Color.FromRgb(255, 99, 71);
        public static readonly Color Turquoise = Color.FromRgb(64, 224, 208);
        public static readonly Color Violet = Color.FromRgb(238, 130, 238);
        public static readonly Color Wheat = Color.FromRgb(245, 222, 179);
        public static readonly Color White = Color.FromRgb(255, 255, 255);
        public static readonly Color WhiteSmoke = Color.FromRgb(245, 245, 245);
        public static readonly Color Yellow = Color.FromRgb(255, 255, 0);
        public static readonly Color YellowGreen = Color.FromRgb(154, 205, 50);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the definition of `NamedColor`. Is it in the same assembly and in the `ListViewDemo` namespace? If the namespace is different, for example; `ListViewDemo.Colors` then you should have that in your `local` definition like: `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ListViewDemo.Colors;assembly=ListViewDemo"`

Comment: @GeraldVersluis I have edited my question and added NamedColor.cs code. Please see the edted code. Both are in same name space 'ListViewDemo'

Comment: Are they also in the same project?

Comment: @GeraldVersluis yes, all files are in the same project.

Comment: Then I don't see any reason for it not to work. There is however one thing that caught my attention; in the screenshot it says it can't be found in xmlns. If it was looking for local, I think it should be mentioned in the error message. Not 100% sure though.. Make sure you clean and rebuild everything. Is there any way I can have a look at your code?

Comment: Tell me how can I help you? I can share the code files if you wish.

Comment: If you could share it in a Github repo or something then I can have a look

Comment: @GeraldVersluis Please find the code @ https://github.com/Gagan5278/ListViewExample

Comment: The repository is empty

Comment: @GeraldVersluis sorry for the delay. I am unable to upload whole project neither on GIT nor Dropbox because of network but I have uploaded file on this link https://www.dropbox.com/s/2fbi46kl2gerbm9/Files.zip?dl=0  Please suggest what am I doing wrong.  I have also post the same query to Xamarin support team https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/266051#Comment_266051

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed sometimes, when a class is only referenced in XAML, the linker strips it away from the final app. I've forced it to include it by adding something similar to:

```
private void _forceLinking() {
    var unused = new Full.Namespace.NamedColor();
}
```

in my `App.xaml.cs` class. There is probably a better way to do this, but at least this works and fixed the issue for me.